# About connection and topology

Tags: reference-request, math-history

I'm looking for a good book (or article) about history of topology, and specially about the connection concept. I appreciate all your suggestions!!!

Comment: Do you mean "connectivity"? As in a connected set $(0,1)$ versus a disconnected set $(0,1/3) \cup (2/3,1)$?  Or the more geometric notion of a connection in the sense of the tangent bundle?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out the historical notes and references at the end of Chapter 2 in [Dudley (2002](http://books.google.com/books?id=7UuT7UZViN0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=hu&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false),  pp. 75–84).